# How to bring the value of an element separately from each component in a console

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have this elements in my page HTML

```
<div class="widget-content"><i class="rgCate" data-type="single" data-len="5" data-label="recent"></i></div>
<div class="widget-content"><i class="rgCate" data-type="single" data-len="5" data-label="recent"></i></div>
<div class="widget-content"><i class="rgCate" data-type="single" data-len="5" data-label="recent"></i></div>
```

and i want get a `data-type` value individually, in the sense that it comes with the value of each element separately from the other and not together.

I tried bringing value separately in this way but it didn't work for me as the value comes together

```
$(".cate-sections .widget").each(function(){
var e=$(this);
var dataTypeAttr = e.find('.rgCate').attr("data-type");
console.log(dataTypeAttr);
});
```

so i want help about this ..

Comment: What do you mean the "value comes together"?

Comment: Keeping in mind that you are performing a loop over every widget ...

Comment: @Taplar I mean when I print it in the console it collects their value for it, which is `single` in one print. I want each item separately from the other. Do you understand me, my friend?

Comment: It is printing them separately.  It's printing the same value for each element.  Are you perhaps getting confused because browser consoles can condense console logs to a single entry if they match?  You should see a number on the right hand side of the log showing how many times it has logged.

Comment: `console.log(Date.now(), dataTypeAttr);` would force the browser to not condense the console logs for illustration

Comment: @Taplar 
But it also prints history

Comment: What are you calling "history"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML posted here seems incomplete, though refer below code for available HTML here. You should loop on class".widget-content"

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".widget-content").each(function(){
    var e=$(this);
    var dataTypeAttr = e.find('.rgCate').attr("data-type");
    alert(dataTypeAttr);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget-content"><i class="rgCate" data-type="single" data-len="5" data-label="recent"></i></div>
<div class="widget-content"><i class="rgCate" data-type="Double" data-len="5" data-label="recent"></i></div>
<div class="widget-content"><i class="rgCate" data-type="Triple" data-len="5" data-label="recent"></i></div>
```

Comment: Given that the OP says something does log, that would point more towards they need to provide an accurate representation of their html.  That's more of a comment clarification that needs to be asked, not an answer

Comment: Okay, Thank you for clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup the right Selector. Since your `data-type` attribute is on the `i` element you want to target them.

```js
$(".widget-content .rgCate").each(function(i, el) {
  console.log(i, $(el).data("type"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget-content"><i class="rgCate" data-type="single" data-len="5" data-label="recent"></i></div>
<div class="widget-content"><i class="rgCate" data-type="single" data-len="5" data-label="recent"></i></div>
<div class="widget-content"><i class="rgCate" data-type="single" data-len="5" data-label="recent"></i></div>
```

You can also use `this` or `$(this)` to reference the element .

Comment: This is doing the same thing as the OP just using the passed in element and data() instead of attr().  They are logically the same

Comment: @Taplar yes you are correct, and I added the Index to the console which will address your other comment. Just condensed code, same logic.

Comment: So, what issue is actually being solved, other than the OP misreading the console? :)  Additionally I know there has to be a duplicate for this

Comment: @Taplar his selector was not matching any of the elements and referenced an element that did not exist in the example. It's also sharing more information about the usage of `.each()`. And, as you stated, helping clarify his misunderstanding, if OP has one.

Comment: If it didn't match in his actual code, he would have seen nothing log.  He is seeing things log.  He's saying the logs are grouped.

Comment: @Taplar 
See this result is printed to me

Comment: 1581011995942 "single"
1581011995951 "single"
1581011995962 "single"

Comment: Right ... there are three elements, so you're printing each one's data type.  You haven't stated what is incorrect about that. @MSDesCUC  Also these commentes should be in your top question, not to a response of an answer

Comment: @Taplar Sorry I did not notice